# Jenkins Sonar Scanner "Load Active Rules" sometimes takes 40 minutes

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have  jenkins Job which use Sonar Plugin to execute sonar scanning and analysis.
There is a step in the execution which is termed as **"load Active Rules"**. This step sometimes takes 2 minutes to complete, and sometimes it takes upto 40 minutes.
The Build slave, sonarqube server, the project Key and the Profile are always unchanged.

```
Sonar Plugin version : 2.2.1
Jenkins version : 2.60.3
```

Can anyone help me in understanding What could be reason behind this?  Could this be a problem with a Sonar server config Or jenkins/Plugin config?